# dyanmically add multiple UITextviews with new UITextView above the old UITextview

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextview, autolayout

I have a `UITextView` for adding comments to an article. Below this `UITextView` is a `UIButton` named **'Add Another Comment'**. On Clicking this `UIButton`, another `UITextView` must be created such that the old `UITextView` gets pushed below the new one. I must be able to do this how many ever times i want.

EDIT: my problem is not creating the `UITextView` but pushing the old textview below the new one. This is how it should be:

[image]

**a) Before opening up the comments section**

[image]

**b) After opening up the comments section**

Comment: when you say the old one goes "below" the new one, does the old one also go below the button? as in all the old comments are pushed below the button and the textview for the new comment always goes above the button?

Comment: @jancakes the old textview along with the button gets pushed below the new textview i.e.,only a fresh textview appears pushing the default textview and the button downwards when i click 'Add another comment'.

Answer (score 0):

Hi John yes you can create uitextfield after clicking the button for that you have to write code as such below

```
- (IBAction)addText:(id)sender
{
CGRect textfieldFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 30.0);
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:textfieldFrame];
textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
textField.placeholder = @"enter text";
textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;    
textField.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:textField];



}
```

[this link also use full for the reference](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/27065-how-to-dynamically-create-text-field-uitextfield.html)

Answer (score 0):

just change the y position of the old textview in animation block

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{

// set center = btn.y+btn height+0.5*tetview height + any space below button if you want

}];

I have few doubts
Are using scroll view ? how user will see previous comments ? also what if the text height is larger than the height of textview ?

Comment: Yes, i am using a UIView added as a subview to UIScrollView. Check EDIT. In the first image, you can see a **'Notes & comments'** button. On Clicking, it opens up a list of comment boxes(UITextViews) saved already. This is illustrated in the second image where two comment boxes(there can be many of course!) can be seen. I am not concerned about text height now.